# FaceBook friends.getAppUsers replacement

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to find friends who have already installed the application. After doing much research I found that FaceBook has a way to do this however it is marked as legacy.

Is there a new way to do this via the graph API? Comparing UID's one by one to people already in my database would be way to slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook FQL queries are still supported and not deprecated, so you could run a query like:

```
SELECT uid, name FROM user
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
AND is_app_user = 1
```

with a url like (url encode this and add your users access token):

[https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1&access_token=...](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20uid,%20name%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20=%20me%28%29%29%20AND%20is_app_user%20=%201&access_token=...)

However I have found this to be more reliable to do against my own database.  If you setup indexing properly and do a IN sql statement it should be really fast as you wouldn't need to do it one by one.